# Signalr self-hosted Hub in an Azure Web Job requires elevation?

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, azure-webjobs

I'd like to use a SignalR self hosted project in a continuous Azure Web Job. But when I attempt to run it, I get the following error:

```
[07/11/2014 10:58:44 > cbec50: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[07/11/2014 10:58:45 > cbec50: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
```

I suppose the console app needs to run with elevated rights. Is there any way to get this to work?

**Prerequisites**:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Jobs -pre
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost
```

**Full source:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Jobs;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080/"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");

                var host = new JobHost(); 
                host.RunAndBlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a [response from David Ebbo](https://twitter.com/davidebbo/status/487632925232353280) (@davidebbo):

```
"...you can only listen on a port through IIS. 
WebJobs are more to do work and not run services."
```

I had considered web jobs as a good way to host a Signalr Hub without the an entire website footprint, but I'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: Hey @Jarem what alternative did you use? I was planning to do the exact same thing.